# Add Service Reference Error

Tags: c#, wcf, service, web, reference

I am trying to use a .wsdl file from my own wcf project. From what i understand of it, i need to add the service reference of the .wsdl file into my wcf project. The error is am getting is this one :

The document was understood, but it could not be processed.

The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.

- There was an error downloading    'http://address.com/myservice.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
- Unable to connect to the remote server
- A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.7.6.60:80 If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I have been searching about this error but the only solution i get is to add the proxy address but we are not using any proxy.

Comment: You need to have the service running to get at the linked documents/files in the WSDL (like http://address.com/myservice.svc?xsd=xsd0')

Comment: if you copy/paste the problematic link into a browser, what do you see?

Comment: "Oops! Google Chrome could not find address.com"